# selenium movetoelement not working after navigate back

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='topNav"+menue+"']"));
      new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();
```

This code for the first time works fine and I can click on link and go to new page.

Now I need to go back to previous page which is home page, so I use:

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

after this line even if I do the same first two line above not working

and I used

`driver.navigate.refresh();`

or

```
driver.navigate().to("mysite.com");
```

still not working.

selenium version is 2.53.1  and firefox version 46.0
and I tried the other version of selenium and firefox

please let me know what is the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem this way:

First before executing:

driver.navigate().back(), when we are in the initial home page,  save the current page:

String home =driver.getCurrentUrl();

Then every time I need to go back to home page instead of using:

driver.navigate().back();     I just use:

driver.get(home);

and now we are in the home page and moveToElemnt works fine:

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

or just add  `Thread.sleep(5000);` instead after `driver.navigate().back();`

Comment: Pankaj2602  thanks for your reply I know that we have to wait until the page load completely I tried that and also I use debugging mode and run step by step and some other people complain about problem with driver.navigate().back(). did you try yourself action  method this way.